# Debugging jquery .map that generates html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate some rows and cells in a given table based on an object's key-value pairs.

As seen in the jQuery below, I'm trying to use `.map` to do this.

**JavaScript object:**

```
  response = {
    ...
    'details': { 
      'Email': employee.email_work,
      'Slack': employee.username_slack,
    }
  }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.map(response.details, function(key, val) {

     $("#details-tbl").append([
         $("td").addClass('detail-key').text(key),
         $("td").addClass('detail-value-holder').append(
             $("span").attr('data-resp', key).text(val)
         )
     ]);
 });
```

**desired html:**

```
<table id="details-tbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="detail-key">
            "[KEY]"
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="detail-value" data-resp="[KEY]">
                "[VAL]"
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The desired HTML is not showing up. There are no errors being thrown.

Can I use object keys as strings?

Comment: You'll want to use `$("<td>")` instead of `$("td")`. The latter *searches* for a `td`; the first *creates* a new one. Same for `span`.

Comment: `$('td')` does not create a new element it searches for one with the tag name `td`. You need to write `$('<td>')` instead.